# Initialising a python interactive plot to improve responsiveness

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-interactive

I'm creating an interactive plot which has some lines and annotations etc. A minimum working example is:

```
def make_plot(scale_factor):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))  # create a figure object
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    
    x = np.linspace(0,10)
    y = np.sin(x)*scale_factor
    
    ax.set_ylim(0,10)
    ax.axhline(2,c='k')
    
    plt.plot(x,y)
    
def make_interactive_plot():

    scale_factor_slider = wg.FloatSlider(value=1,
                                           min=0,
                                           max=5,
                                           step=0.1,
                                           description=r'Scaling Factor')


    wg.interact(make_plot,
                scale_factor = scale_factor_slider)
    
make_interactive_plot()
```

This works fine, but as the plot gets more complicated, I'd like to not *replot it* every time I change a value with a slider. I'd like to just update the Line2D object. This is the common implementation of matplotlib.animation functionality. I'd like to do something like this:

```
def update_plot(line_obj,scale_factor):
    
    print(scale_factor)
    x = np.linspace(0,10)
    y = np.sin(x)*scale_factor
    
    line_obj.set_data(x,y)
    
def make_interactive_plot():

    scale_factor_slider = wg.FloatSlider(value=1,
                                           min=0,
                                           max=5,
                                           step=0.1,
                                           description=r'Scaling Factor')


    wg.interact(update_plot,
                line_obj = line_obj,
                scale_factor = scale_factor_slider)
    
    
# Initialise plot just once

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))  # create a figure object
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0,10)
ax.axhline(2,c='k')

line_obj, = ax.plot([],[])
    
make_interactive_plot()
```

Unfortunately this throws:
`ValueError: <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7fb1dd3577d0> cannot be transformed to a widget`

Does anybody know if modifying an object to update an interactive plot is possible?